# How to load local HTML file in Phonegap Android?

Tags: android, cordova

I've tried to load local html file in my application using Phonegap Android but always end with fullscreen html page shown.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- my header code -->
<div data-role="content" id="termsContent">
    <iframe id="frame" src="tnc.html" width="100%" height="100%">
    </iframe>
</div>
<!-- my footer code -->
```

I simply load the html file to my iframe tag.
Is my implementation wrong?

Comment: How you want it to be display??

Comment: I've edited my post.. I want to display it inside the div of content only. I have another code as the header and footer.

Comment: try to add some width and height for the div.

Comment: I tried it to set both width and height 100 but it's still fullscreen :(

Comment: 100%??? If so, try changing to 50% and 50% respectively.

Comment: where is tnc.html, it should be inside www